# Caliburn.Micro WPF: IoC.Get Returns Null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

My code looks like this:

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(sender, e);
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        _container.RegisterPerRequest(typeof(ShellViewModel), null, typeof(ShellViewModel));   
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
```

And my `ShellViewModel` looks like this:

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>
{
    public ShellViewModel
    {
        var aViewModel = IoC.Get<AViewModel>();
        ActivateItem(aViewModel);
    }
}
```

But whenever I run the program, a blank screen is shown. When I debug it, it said that the `aViewModel` is `null`.

Is there anything wrong with the `Bootstrapper`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code provided, `AViewModel` is not registered with the container in the Bootstrapper so `IoC` does not know it exists, thus it will return null when requested to `Get` that type

For example

```
_container.RegisterPerRequest(typeof(AViewModel), null, typeof(AViewModel));
```

All types that need to be resolved by `IoC` should first be registered with the backing container.

Comment: Quick question, do you register all of your viewmodels for navigation or do you have other ways for navigation?

Comment: Anything that need to be resolved by the container needs to be registered in the container. that would include your viewmodels.